# Does Stripe and CiviCRM work on Drupal 8 and Webform?

Tags: webform-civicrm, drupal-8, stripe

I have installed: Stripe 6.5.5;  CiviCRM 5.32.2;  Drupal 8.9.11;  Webform 6.0.0;  Webform_civicrm 8.x-5.0-beta4.

When I try to make a (test) Donation payment I get the error:

```
Error
Unable to complete payment! Missing paymentIntentID.
```

Is this a configuration problem or does D8 not work yet?

Comment: That’s a Stripe specific error message - I’ll ping MattW in Drupal channel on CiviCRM Mattermost

Comment: Do you have https://civicrm.org/extensions/contribution-transact-api installed?

Comment: Yes, the https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/contributiontransactlegacy extension v1.3 is installed.  (I got the same error before I remembered this, as well.)

Comment: I'm also getting this error on D7 Webform

Answer (score 1):

Stripe 6.5.6 has a Fix for this.  (I haven't tested it personally, but it looks good.)

Answer (score 1):

Stripe is working with webform civicrm D8/D9 complete with test coverage.